# i'm having problems using axios and making requests to a api

Tags: javascript, api, axios

```
const getCustomers = async (token) => {
try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${base_url}/customers`,  { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`} })
    return response.data
} catch(error) {
    logger.error(error)
}
```

i'm using axios to make a request to an api, and i keep getting the same error.

```
error: undefined {"config":{"url":"https://api.contaazul.com/v1/customers","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer EU5KBm8ft1ZB4vFy9I89xYQWnzqcbULS","User-Agent":"axios"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1},"code":"HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN"}
```

already tried deleting node_modules and using other versions of node

Comment: I would [search for the error code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN). [Seems to bring back a few hits when entered on an internet search engine too](https://www.bing.com/search?q=HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN&FORM=ANCMS9&PC=U531). Seems to be malformed headers coming back from NodeJS. You'll need to show those headers for anyone to help.

Comment: Have you tried making the same get request through Postman (an HTTP client)? That might help you debug.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const getCustomers = async (token) => {
    await axios.get(`${base_url}/customers`, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ` + token
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
}
```